# Python iterate through 2000 images in directory, return lowest number

Tags: python

The code below scans through a folder for images and chooses the file that is closest to 0.

But `e` only catches the first ~30, like if I had an `img_50.png` the script wouldn't pick it up. It would be ideal to return an image up to 2000 like `img_2000.png`

Not sure where I went wrong, I'm using `os.listdir` but it seems to not be grabbing past ~30 images

```
e = 0
for image_file in os.listdir(folder_path + local_username + "/"):
    print("in for loop")
    try:
        print("Hit try")
        fileInput.send_keys(folder_path + local_username + "/img_" + str(e) + ".png")
        print("Selected image from folder")
    except:
        e += 1
        print("Hit except")
```

It prints this out, only iterates through twice

```
in for loop
Hit try
Hit except
in for loop
Hit try
Hit except
```

Comment: you seem to be scanning/checking images in **only** one folder, how many images does this folder have?

Comment: @sai 2000 images

Comment: why don't you use `Path(folder_path + local_username + "/").glob('*.png')`, this will give you a generator that you can iterate to read all your images.

Comment: shouldn't you be incrementing e inside 'try' block also?

Comment: @sai `    for image_file in glob.iglob(folder_path + local_username + "/").glob('*.png'):
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'glob'`

Comment: @mattwelter - what is that line you just asked about in your comment?  What is the `glob.iglob` part supposed to do?  That's not what @sai proposed.

Comment: @Steve 

I put e = 0 inside the for loop and used his method `fileInput.send_keys(path(folder_path + local_username + "/").glob('*.png'))` but the same error occured

Comment: @sai I put e = 0 inside the for loop and used his method `fileInput.send_keys(path(folder_path + local_username + "/").glob('*.png'))` but the same error occured

Answer (score 0):

Original

```
e = 0
for image_file in os.listdir(folder_path + local_username + "/"):
    print("in for loop")
    try:
        print("Hit try")
        fileInput.send_keys(folder_path + local_username + "/img_" + str(e) + ".png")
        print("Selected image from folder")
    except:
        e += 1
        print("Hit except")
```

This worked:

```
e = 0
for image_file in range(0,2000):
    print("in for loop")
    try:
        print("Hit try")
        fileInput.send_keys(folder_path + local_username + "/img_" + str(e) + ".png")
        print("Selected image from folder")
    except:
        e += 1
        print("Hit except")
```

Comment: It is good that it is working, but it would be better to improve for the sake of striving to be good! For starters, now your code won't be flexible to handle if you were to add more images. Secondly, the except block should handle usually foreseeable errors, such as 'FileNotFoundError' in this particular case. Finally, `Path(folder_path + local_username + "/").glob('*.png')`, if you're not aware of this module, `Path` is a module part of  `pathlib` package and can be used by importing  like this `from pathlib import Path`